# How to launch windows machine with Microsoft Edge browser in Cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, google-cloud-platform, cloud

Need to launch windows machine with Microsoft Edge browser in the cloud.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do create a Windows 10 VM in most cloud, like Azure or AWS. You also have the option to do create virtual desktops. If sounds like you want to do browser testing, if that is the case, then I would encourage you to consider something like https://www.browserstack.com/.

If this doesn't answer you question, can you please add additional details.